# Is possible duplicate or copy test sets templates from ALM using a Jenkins job?

Tags: jenkins, hp-uft, alm

We are looking for a way to duplicate or copy the test sets we have in ALM but using a Jenkins job or even a Jenkins plugin.

The idea we have in mind is to duplicate/copy test sets that we have as templates in ALM with their corresponding execution flows. These "plans" must be created automatically when we have to execute a specific release.

I have seen that the Bumblebee plugin exists for Jenkins but it would not be useful to us since we have seen that it is only valid for unit tests when ours must be executed in a certain order (flows created in ALM), hence we have to duplicate or copy the templates that we use. we have in ALM.

Is there a relatively simple way to carry out this process through Jenkins?

We are looking for possible solutions to what we are proposing here but they would not be valid:

https://bumblebee.agiletestware.com/ci-integration/jenkins

https://sumeetkushwah.com/2017/10/08/creating-test-plan-folders-using-ota-api/